# How do I delete a copied repo without affecting the original repo?

Tags: git, command-line, terminal

What happened: I copied folderA into folderX. Moved files out of folderA one level so they're directly under folderX now (this is what I should have done in the first place but I'm new to this so we are). I don't want folderA in folderX but the original folderA should not be altered.

Question(s): 
When I "rm -r folderA" that's located in folderX, I get this message:

> rm: remove write-protected regular file
>   'folderX/.git/objects/00/many999letters123many456numbers'?

- Should I say yes? Will removing the copied folder affect the original?
- Is it better to undo my mistake of copying the folder? How would I do that?

More info: 
I haven't pushed any changes to github yet. folderX is a repo (currently with no files except .git and readme.txt). folderA is also a repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the extra copy in `folderA/folderX`, there is no harm in deleting all of `folderA/folderX/.git`.

The write-protected files in `folderA/.git/objects/00` through `folderA/.git/objects/ff` are git objects (blobs, trees, commits, and tags) that encode the various pieces of your repository’s history in “loose format.”